# Postman. Get a token. Error: "Missing parameter: \" code \ "is required"

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, postman

In POSTMAN, I want to get a token. I entered and I chose the following data:

```
1) POST: https://app.com/oauth2/token
2) Body
3) x-www-form-urlencoded
4) username: ****
5) password: ****
6) grant_type: authorization_code
7) client_secret: ****
7) client_id: ****
```

I get error:

> {
>       "error": "invalid_request",
>       "error_description": "Missing parameter: \"code\" is required" }

What `code` is required? How to get it?

**Updated**

I found in documentation:
`code` it is base64.encode(username + ':' + password).

How to generate it, pass it in postman?

Comment: Consult the vendors documentation. It looks like you need to pass a paramter named `code`. Not sure what goes into it though. They should have that clearly documented.

Answer (score 1):

The request is the 2nd step of the [Authorization Code flow](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/).

You have specified `grant_type: authorization_code`

> The Authorization Code grant type is used by confidential and public
>   clients to exchange an authorization code for an access token.
>
> After the user returns to the client via the redirect URL, the
>   application will get the authorization code from the URL and use it to
>   request an access token.

You must call the authorization server to obtain the authorization code and next you can call the specified url https://app.com/oauth2/token for obtain the access token.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
var base64encodedvalue = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('username'+':'+'password');
var code = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(base64encodedvalue);
console.log(code);
```